# gwt service 404 not found

Tags: java, gwt

Приветствую! Пытаюсь использовать gwt сервис для связи бекенда и фронтенда. Но почему-то ловится метод onFailure.

```
@Override
public void start(HasWidgets display, NavigationPlace place) {

    display.add((Widget)view);
    String token = Window.Location.getParameter("token");
    loginService.verifyToken("123", new AsyncCallback<SessionDTO>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) throws IncompatibleRemoteServiceException {

            view.setText(throwable.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SessionDTO sessionDTO) {
            clientSessionManager.initSession(sessionDTO);
            homeActivity.get().start(view.getContentPanelMain(), null);
        }
    });

}
```

И реализация сервиса:

```
@Singleton
@WebServlet(name = ServletMappingConstants.LOGIN_SERVICE_NAME, urlPatterns =         ServletMappingConstants.LOGIN_SERVICE_URL)
public class LoginServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements     LoginService {
public SessionDTO verifyToken(String token) {
    if (token.equals("123")){
        return new SessionDTO();
    }

    return new SessionDTO();
}
```

В чем может быть причина неудачи?